# Could not connect to existing session of Brave using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, brave

I am trying to connect to existing session of Brave using puppeteer. But the program is throwing an error after opening an empty tab in the existing Brave window.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
    try {
        // const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
        //     browserWSEndpoint: 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080' // replace XXXXX with the actual endpoint for the running Brave instance
        // });

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            userDataDir: "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser",
            "headless": false,
            "defaultViewport": null,
            "args": ['--start-maximized'],
            //args: ["--no-sandbox"],
            executablePath: '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser' // path to Brave executable
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://google.com');
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
        //await page.close();
        // await page.click('#myButton'); // replace with the selector for the element to click
        // await browser.close();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

The error that gets thrown is

> Error: Failed to launch the browser process!

I tried to connect using browserWSEndpoint, but I couldn't find it. Brave inspect tab is showing me an empty page

[image]